# Centering embed PDF content

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I have a PDF file embed inside my web page. My HTML is:

```
<embed src="http://znaci.net/zb/4_1_19.pdf">
```

My CSS is:

```
embed {
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
}
```

Now I have a situation like this:

[image]

But I need this:

[image]

Is there a way to center embed PDF content?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the height and width via CSS like such:

```
<style>
    embed {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

You also control it via attributes in the `embed` tag like such:

```
<embed src="http://znaci.net/zb/4_1_19.pdf" width="640" height="480">
```

As for the zoom, you can achieve this by doing the following (note the #zoom=75):

```
<embed src="http://znaci.net/zb/4_1_19.pdf#zoom=75">
```

This syntax worked in IE11 and FF32, but not in Chrome 38.

---

Edit: Answer to the centering part of the question:

Centering the PDF only fails in Chrome. A work around for this can be to replace the `embed` tag with an iFrame like such (though I don't think this is the best practice).

```
<iframe src="http://znaci.net/zb/4_1_19.pdf"></iframe>
```

Alternatively, you can look at some thing like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to center a PDF inside embed tag. I have updated my question with pictures. Any ideas how to do this?